# VB.net Windows 8.1 Store App save listviews & appbartogglebutton state when app closes

Tags: vb.net, xaml, listview, windows-8.1

I have an app with many different listviews that i will need saved when the app closes.
(FYI: All of my Listviews only contain one column and I only need to save the items in the listviews, not the headers.)

I will also need the check state of an appbartogglebutton saved on app close.

I have been trying to look into on suspending and things along those lines for saving data when closing an app, but i just can't quite figure it out.

Can anyone help? Thanks for any help in advance!

**Edit: 11/2/2014**

I managed to get the state of a checkbox saved by using this in the checkbox checked event:

```
If roamingSettings.Values.ContainsKey("CheckBox1State") Then
            ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values("CheckBox1State") = CheckBox1.IsChecked.Value
        Else
            roamingSettings.Values.Add("CheckBox1State", False)
            ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values("CheckBox1State") = CheckBox1.IsChecked.Value
        End If
```

And I am using Page_Loaded with this to load the state of the checkbox:

```
If roamingSettings.Values.ContainsKey("CheckBox1State") Then
            CheckBox1.IsChecked = roamingSettings.Values("CheckBox1State")
        End If
```

So I figured out the checkbox, but now I just need to figure out how to save the listviews to the roaming or local settings. That I am still having trouble figuring out. I was thinking maybe using localfolder to grab a storagefile, but even with that i am stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: Like I said, i have been looking into the onsuspending, which meant that i have tried it. It doesn't mean that it doesn't work, its just that I don't know how to get it to work. I'm sure that the solution is along those lines, but I can't get the code quite right. And I'm not even sure how to tell it to save the listviews.

Comment: Which events are you using for your suspension/resume?

Comment: I don't know now. I removed the code, because it doesn't work. This is why I'm asking for help. "What i have tried" and "Which events.." don't matter, because what I've tried doesn't work. I need a thorough example for me to understand, because I'm so clueless as to where to even begin. I need, now, to start with a fresh code for saving when I close the app. Then, I'd like to work from there.

Comment: Sorry if the previous comment came off as rude, I did not intend for it to be. If I am frustrated at all, it's with myself, not you. But, if you have an idea as to how to help me, please do. This part of the app is hindering me from completing it, since this is the final stage of my app. Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using one of the Visual Studio template projects, take a look at the `NavigationHelper` class it added, which has XML documentation on setting it up - you'd then just need to implement something in your event handlers for `LoadState` and `SaveState` events to store the values you're wanting to maintain across calls somewhere.

Comment: That all makes sense, but I don't know how to implement that and I don't know where exactly to put that.